# (Terminology) Operation taking matrices to a block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, terminology

What is the name of the map defined by
$$
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{Mat}_{n\times m} & \rightarrow \operatorname{Mat}_{kn\times km}\\
(A_1,\dots,A_k) & \mapsto 
   \begin{bmatrix}
    A_{1}       & 0 & 0  \\
    0   & A_2   & 0 \\
    \dots \\
    0        & \dots & A_{k}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called a direct sum. The direct sum of $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_k$ is usually denoted by $A_1\oplus A_2\oplus\cdots\oplus A_k$ or $\bigoplus_{i=1}^kA_i$.

Comment: Perfect, is there a standard book which I can put down as a reference?

Comment: @AIM_BLB See Horn and Johnson's *Matrix Analysis* or Hoffman and Kunze's *Linear Algebra*.

Comment: Thank you.  Also perhaps related is this post:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3542651/numbers-of-zero-entries-in-matrix-direct-sum