# Numbers of zero entries in matrix direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, combinations, direct-sum

Let $A_0,\dots,A_n$ be matrices in $\operatorname{Mat}_{M_0\times N_0},\dots,\operatorname{Mat}_{M_n\times N_n}$, respectively, all with no zero entries.  Then how many non-zero entries does $\oplus_{i=0}^n A_i$ have; where the matrix direct sum is defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_addition#Direct_sum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A_i$ has $M_iN_i$ non zero entries, hence $\oplus_{i=0}^n A_i$ has $\sum_{i=0}^nM_iN_i$ non zero entries.$

Comment: So the $\oplus_{i=0}^n A_i$ has $\left(\sum_{i=0}^n M_i\right)\left(
\sum_{i=0}^n N_i
\right) - \sum_{i=0}^n M_iN_i$ zero entries?